# How to find, copy and paste values between some tags

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to extract the value of id= from a large HTML file. Can help me to do this in notepad++? I tried to understand how to work with notepad++ and regex but I can make it works.

So, i have more similar code like this in ore single html:

```
<div class="clearfix" id="member_100004918089327"><a class=
```

and I want to extract only "**member_100004918089327**"

Can help me to find a way to select and copy this code in a new np++ tab when the notepad search function finds a new value?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can't parse html (reliably) with regex. Notepad++ has no functionality to list matches in a new file. You're better off writing something in another language, preferably one with an xml library.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for any `id` attribute with the following regluar expression: `id\s*=\s*("|')(.*?)\1` Just make sure to tick the *regular expression* radio button in the search dialogue.

[image]

Comment: works good, but it is posible to record a macro to copy and paste after this selection? The steps should be:

Comment: Sorry, accidentaly I press enter and I can edit. So, 
Steps:
1. Find,
2. Copy,
3. Switch to another tab
4. Paste
5. Repeat from step 1